# Attach CSV to email in Python without the CSV

Tags: python, pandas, email, mime

I've seen a number of solutions about sending a CSV as an attachment in an email via Python.

In my case, my Python code needs to extract data from a Snowflake view and send it to a user group as a CSV attachment.  While I know how I can do it using to_csv out of a Pandas dataframe, my question is: Do I have to create the CSV file externally at all?  Can I simply run the Pandas DF through MIMEText?  If so, what file name do I use in the header?

Comment: No need to create the file on disk, you could store the data in a stream (BytesIO, for example) and attach it to your email as a CSV file.

Comment: "what file name do I use in the header" -- anything you want. It's just a string but I suggest you append the .csv extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create a temporary CSV file on disk, but you also can't just "attach a dataframe" since it'd have no specified on-wire format. Use a `BytesIO` to have Pandas serialize the CSV to memory:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
bio = io.BytesIO()
df.to_csv(bio, mode="wb", ...)
bio.seek(0)  # rewind the in-memory file

# use the file object wherever a file object is supported
# or extract the binary data with `bio.getvalue()`
```

Comment: Thanks a million, this will help a lot

Comment: As a follow-up, the StringIO ended up working much better than the BytesIO

Comment: StringIOs and BytesIOs are different beasts. Glad things worked out for you anyway :)